# Jordans elimination float to float argument

Tags: c++, dev-c++

So I was trying to work on a code about [Jordan's elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). When I encountered a problem:

> Cannot convert 'float' to 'float (*)[100]' for argument '1' to 'int diabase(float (*)[100])

What does this mean? And how can I fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 100

int read(float A[N][N]);
int jordan(float A[N][N],int n);
int print(float A[N][N],int n);

int main()
{
    int i, j, k, n, y;
    float A[N][N+1], c, x[N];
    n = read(A[N][N]);
    jordan(A[N][N]], n);
    print(A[N][N], n);
    return(0);
}

int read(float A[N][N]){
    int n,i,j;
    printf("Enter the size of matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the elements of augmented matrix row-wise:");
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=(n+1); j++)
        {
            printf(" A[%d][%d]:", i,j);
            scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }   
    return n;
}

int print( float A[N][N],int n){
    int i;
    float x[n];
    printf("The solution is:");
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        x[i]=A[i][n+1]/A[i][i];
        printf("n x%d=%fn",i,x[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int jordan(float A[N][N],int n){
    int i,j,k;
    float c;
    for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
    {
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                c=A[i][j]/A[j][j];
                for(k=1; k<=n+1; k++)
                {
                    A[i][k]=A[i][k]-c*A[j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code for readability

Comment: n=read(A[N][N]); you give a float value to function which takes "float A[N][N]" (it is float*[N] type). Try "n=read(A);"

Comment: @user3514538 `float A[N][N]` is **NOT** a `float **`.

Comment: @Holt yes, I correct it

Comment: Also, an array with `k` elements is indexed from `0` to `k - 1`, not `1` to `k`.

Comment: @user3514538: missing parent: `float (*)[N]`.

Answer (score 0):

In all of these function calls

```
n=read(A[N][N]);
jordan(A[N][N]],n);
print(A[N][N],n);
```

You are passing and element of the array instead of the array.  If you want to pass the array you just use the name of the array without any indexes

```
n=read(A);
jordan(A,n);
print(A,n);
```

You are going to run into another problem with this though as your functions expect a 2d array of 100 x 100 but your array you created in `main()` is 100 x 101 which is not going to match.  You either need to make the array in `main()` 100 x 100 or change you function take arrays of 100 x 101

Answer (score 0):

When you do `function (A[N][N])` you are passing a single `float` value to `function`, so here:

```
n = read(A[N][N]);
jordan(A[N][N], n);
print(A[N][N], n);
```

You are passing single values to `read`, `jordan` and `print`. And B.T.W you are accessing cells that do not exist (`A[N]` is out of bound since `A` is `float [N][N + 1]`.

If you want to pass `A` to your function, simply do:

```
n = read(A);
jordan(A, n);
print(A, n);
```

Apart from that, there are some mistakes in your code:

1. Your functions want a `float [N][N]` but `A` is `float [N][N+1]` so you will have to modify something.
2. You are accessing cells from `1` to `n`/`n+1`, C arrays have cells from `0` to `n-1`/`n`, so your loop should go from `0` to `n-1`/`n`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main should be

```
int main()
{
    float A[N][N];
    int n = read(A);
    jordan(A, n);
    print(A, n);
    return(0);
}
```